# Gcc compiler would default consider HEX integer constant variable as unsigned int?

Tags: gcc, unsigned

```
#include<stdio.h>
int  main()
{
    int ret = -1071;

    if(ret == 0xfffffbd1)
        {
            printf("HAHAHA");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

why does the GCC compiler recognize the const variable 0xfffffbd1 as unsigned int as the condition ret == 0xfffffbd1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard says that *[t]he type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented* (paragraph 6.4.4.1/5 in C99), and for hexadecimal types without a suffix, this list is:

- `int`
- `unsigned int`
- `long int`
- `unsigned long int`
- `long long int`
- `unsigned long long int`

Assuming a 32-bit `int` type, `0xfffffbd1` is larger than `INT_MAX` but less than `UINT_MAX`, so the type of the constant is `unsigned int`.

Comment: Dear Florian thanks your comprehensive expation, after get off work, i test edit at home via GCC compiler (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)) and found that the default type of  0xfffffbd1 is a signed integer. so maybe i made a mistake at work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 32 bit int type
At first time:
I defined a signed int ret = -1071 and executed the expression ret == 0xfffffbd1, the default type of const variable 0xfffffbd1 is signed integer(the sign bit is 1, which is a negative number), so result of the expression is TRUE
The second time
I updated the ret type to long long int, let ret = -1071 and executed the expression ret == 0xfffffbd1, the expression result is FALSE, the default type of 0xfffffbd1 is signed long long int(sign bit is 0, which is a positive number), if i updated the right value to 0xfffffffffffffbd1, the result of expression will return TRUE